# How to add Search Filters in android based on Firebase Real-time database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building  an app which ask user to register their name, email, phone no and Blood Type.

Below is my Firebase database structure:

[image]

and my Screenshot of app  is
[image]

How do I add search bar or filters show as per Blood type key , such that user can filters according to Blood Type. If  I in requirment of B negative Blood..I'll  use drop down menu for Blood I need to search and when pressed on search button will only show me the Blood group registered as B negative in firebase Database i.e as per key `blood_group`.

Here is my code I use to upload the user details:

```html
public class EnquiryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //UI
    Button btnRequest;
    EditText edtName,edtBlood,edtPlace,edtMobile,edtEmail;
    //DB
    DatabaseReference mHelper;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //progress
    ProgressDialog mProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enquiry);
        //initialisation
        edtBlood=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enq_blood);
        edtMobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enq_mobile);
        edtEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enq_email);
        edtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enq_name);
        edtPlace=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enq_place);
        btnRequest=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //firebase
        mHelper= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final String mCurrentUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //progress
        mProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setTitle("Loading");
        mProgress.setMessage("Please wait..");

        btnRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mProgress.show();
                String blood=edtBlood.getText().toString();
                String name=edtName.getText().toString();
                String mobile=edtMobile.getText().toString();
                String email=edtEmail.getText().toString();
                String  place=edtPlace.getText().toString();
                String temp=blood.toUpperCase();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(blood)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile)||
                        !TextUtils.isEmpty(place)){

                        HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                        userMap.put("name", name);
                        userMap.put("blood_group",blood);
                        userMap.put("email", email);
                        userMap.put("mobile", mobile);
                        userMap.put("place","Location:- " + place);

                        mHelper.child("Help").child(mCurrentUser).setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                mProgress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered Successfully..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

            }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter the details in all fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

and I retrive the data using below code

```html
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DonorListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mDonorList;

    private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog mDonorProgress;

    private String mCurrent_user_id;

    private View mMainView;

    public DonorListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_donor_list, container, false);

        mDonorList = (RecyclerView)mMainView.findViewById(R.id.donor_recyclerview);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mDonorProgress=new ProgressDialog(getContext());

        mDonorProgress.setTitle("Logging In");
        mDonorProgress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        mDonorProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDonorProgress.show();

        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);


        mDonorList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearVertical = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
       mDonorList.setLayoutManager(linearVertical);

        DividerItemDecoration mDividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
                mDonorList.getContext(),
                linearVertical.getOrientation()
        );
        mDonorList.addItemDecoration(mDividerItemDecoration);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Donors, DonorsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Donors, DonorsViewHolder>(

                Donors.class,
                R.layout.users_single_layout,
                DonorsViewHolder.class,
                mUsersDatabase


        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final DonorsViewHolder donorsViewHolder, Donors donors, int i) {

                donorsViewHolder.setDate(donors.getDate());

                final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

                mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String blood=dataSnapshot.child("blood_group").getValue().toString();
                        String phone=dataSnapshot.child("mobile").getValue().toString();
                        final String email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                        String address=dataSnapshot.child("place").getValue().toString();
                        mDonorProgress.hide();

                        donorsViewHolder.setName(userName);
                        donorsViewHolder.setBlood(blood);
                        donorsViewHolder.setEmail(email);
                        donorsViewHolder.setAddress(address);
                        donorsViewHolder.setPhone(phone);
                        final String uri=phone;

                        donorsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Email", "Call"};

                                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                        //Click Event for each item.
                                        if(i == 0){

                                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                            intent.setType("plain/text");
                                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email });
                                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
                                            getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));

                                        }

                                        if(i == 1){
                                          Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:"+uri));
                                            // callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+uri));
                                            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                            getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);

                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                                builder.show();

                            }
                        });


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        };

        mDonorList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);


    }

    // viewholder class..

    public static class DonorsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public DonorsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }
        public void setBlood(String blood){
            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_blood);
            userStatusView.setText(blood.toUpperCase());
        }
        public void setName(String name){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);
        }

        public void setEmail(String email){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_email);
            userNameView.setText(email);
        }
        public void setPhone(String phone){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_phone);
            userNameView.setText(phone);
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_address);
            address.toUpperCase();
            userNameView.setText(address.toUpperCase());
        }
        public void setDate(String date){


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you need to execute a query which should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("blood_group").equalTo("Blood Group: " +  newText);
```

In which `newText` variable can hold any value you want, `B positive` as well as `B negative`.

So everytime you create a search you should return a new query. So according to this, every time you want to filter on a new condition, you will need to:

1. Create a **new** query based on the new filter:

   ```
   Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("blood_group").equalTo("Blood Group: " +  newText);
   ```
2. Attach a listener to this new created query.
3. Create a new adapter with the results of this new created query, or update the existing one using `notifydatasetchanged()` method.

Comment: it was really nice of you for your such warm and kind feedback...I totally appreciate it ..but problem i build this app learning from some blog post and added few modificaiton from here and there and It has been very quite helpful in understanding much more....Here is my whole project will you please extend your help on how can I add what you have suggested....will be an wonderful experience and opportunity for me to learn this which hardly can be found on search engines or Tutorials about filtering database....Here is the link https://github.com/BlueYeti1881/bloodsamajnepal

Comment: Your project contains almost 1000 lines of code. That's a lot for people to parse and try to provide a solution. You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer, and ask another question containing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if something else comes up.

Comment: You can also wait for other answers but if you think that my answer helped you, please also consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!